# My Vim replace with a regex is throwing a `E488: Trailing characters`

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to find all instances of a Twitter handle, and wrap an anchor tag around them.

```
:%s/\(@[\w]\)/<a href="http://www.twitter.com/\1">\1<\/a>/gc
```

Which gives me:

```
E488: Trailing characters
```

Comment: Either escape all your `/`'s, or use a different delimiter (`,` comes to mind).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When the separator character (`/` in your case) between `{pattern}` and `{string}` is contained in one of those, it must be escaped with a `\`. A trick to avoid that is to use a different separator character, e.g. `#`:

```
:%s#@\(\w\+\)#<a href="http://www.twitter.com/\1">\0</a>#gc
```

PS: If it should do what I think it should do, your pattern is wrong; see my correction.

Comment: Thank you for the initial answer, it worked perfectly.  I'm curious about why we use `/1` to inject the pattern the first time, and `/0` to inject it the second time.

Comment: Oh, wait.  I think I get it.  The `/0` will inject the entire word, and the `/1` will inject just the part that was captured.

Answer (score 56):

If you have this when replacing within a selected block of text, it may be because you mistakenly typed `%s` when you should only type `s`

I had this happen by selecting a block, typing `:` and at the prompt `:'<,'>`, typing `%s/something/other/` resulting in `:'<,'>%s/something/other/` when the proper syntax is `:'<,'>s/something/other/` without the percent.

Comment: This was exactly my issue, %s is such an ingrained habit :D

Comment: Wow, I never expected this obscure answer to get so many points. If I knew how to work on vim and had the interest, I would make a more reasonable error message.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and couldn't make it go away until I found out that the `.vimrc` file that I had parts that I copied from else where that contained abbreviations, like this for example:

`abbrev gc !php artisan generate:controller`

That abbreviation would mess up my search and replace commands which usually look like this:

`:%s/foo/bar/gc`

by expanding that `gc` into `!php artisan generate:controller`, except, that it wouldn't do it on the spot/ in real time. The way that I clued in was by looking through the command history (by pressing `:` and the up arrow) and seeing

`:%s/foo/bar/!php artisan generate:controller`

So if you're getting trailing character errors no matter what you do I'd look inside

`~/.vimrc`

and see if you can find the problem there.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

Only using other delimiters didn't help. So, additionally

1. I didn't select any row.
2. And didn't use g for global.

so just

```
:%s#to_be_replaced#replacement#
```

did the job. Changed all occurrences of 'to_be_replaced' with 'replacement'.

Answer (score 2):

`:%s/\/apps/log_dir/g`

where string to replace=/apps
and replaced string=log_dir
as we saw / so we need to use `"\/"`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I caused my "**E488: Trailing characters**"
Occasionally the muscle memory in my brain skips a beat as it did today causing me to seek the reason for my E488: Trailing characters.

*:%s/searchItem/changeTo/**s***
The **s** at the end caused my E488: Trailing characters.

I should have used a **g**

*:%s/searchItem/changeTo/**g***
Placing the **g** at the end worked as always.